# In PHPStorm, is it neccessary to create new Run Configs for every project?

Tags: php, ide, xdebug, phpstorm

I've been reading through the documentation, but my mind is a swirling flurry of how to approach project-creation and executing within this IDE.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to write PHP code within the IDE, click "Run", and then have that code launch inside a browser (preferably with xdebug interaction). It seems that to do this, one must edit/create a new Run Configuration (using the PHP Web Application template in this case).

But does this have to be done for every project/file? Is it possible to set a default Run Config that will launch all subsequent project files in the same manner (launching in a browser with a debug session)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to create such a default for all the projects. You can also consider using [zero configuration debugging](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/02/zero-configuration-debugging-with-xdebug-and-phpstorm-2-0/) so that you don't have to create the Run configuration at all.